# HTML navbar color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This may be a silly question. But I could really use some help.

So I know that using `navbar-inverse` in HTML can change the colour of the navbar.

But I'm not sure how to change the color of the text. What do I need to write on the CSS?

Comment: What framework are you using? Can you put some code you used?

Comment: Im using asp.net mvc5

Comment: Are you using bootstrap for css

Comment: Yes im using bootstrap too

Comment: This sounds like a CSS question and very little, if anything, to do with the Visual Studio IDE or the server-side MVC framework. Please post the HTML involved. navbar-inverse sounds like a bootstrap CSS class (although of course it needn't be exclusive to bootstrap) so I've tagged that in anticipation. You can edit it if that's not the case. In CSS you can use the `color` property to set the colour of text within a selected element (or elements). You can study the basics of CSS and also find reference documentation in many places online.

Comment: @ADyson if you have any reference on where i can learn this, it would be very helpful. Thankyou

Comment: just google "CSS tutorial" and "CSS reference" and you'll get loads of results!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to see a working solution inline, you can simply add:

```
 style="color: white;"
```

into your nav class.

E.g

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="color: white;">
 Test.
 </nav>
```

Alternatively, in a separate CSS file, you can give a colour definition to a class. Such as :

```
.nav-color-change{
color: white;
}
```

And then use the class "nav-color-change" in your nav bar class.

E.g

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse nav-color-change">
Test
</nav>
```

If you would like this to work only on links as well, simply amend the CSS class to the following:

```
.nav-color-change ul li a{
color: white;
}

.nav-color-change ul li a:hover{
color: grey;
}
```

To see this in an example, change your HTML also to:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse nav-color-change">
<ul>
<li>
<a>Test 1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a>Test 2</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Remember to link to your alternative CSS file in your  tag. So if you're css file is called "test-style.css" then you must write:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="link/to/path/css/test-style.css">
```

Where the "link/to/path" leads you to the folder you'll find your css in.